# Testing binding on angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, unit-testing

Can somebody give some hints about this question?
I have this form in angular with an input to save a patient name in db using a function save() in the **Component1**.

```html
 <form  name="editForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" #editForm="ngForm">
 
 <input #inputValid type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="field_nombre"
                 [(ngModel)]="paciente.nombre" required/>
```

This form closes itself on save and I should see the result on the html page of the other component Component2. Its html is like this:

```html
    <div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="pacientes">
     <tr *ngFor="let paciente of pacientes ;trackBy: trackId">
                <td>{{paciente.nombre}}</td>
                ....
```

**I have actually tested that the data is saved I mean the save function, and also that the button submit calls save.**

I want to unit- test the front end part using Jasmine,  that this data that I saved previously appears in my table. How can I do this? Until now I can use ViewChild to take the references of input and the table but I need a hint on how actually to test it.The angular tutorial on testing does not includes examples like this.
Thanks,

Comment: @trichetriche  can you give me  a hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, you can give a class name to your tr element and count ngfor elements after submit and check that it is not equal to 0 and that the elements length is passed from 0 to 1 and add an id to your form "id='FormId'"

```
<form  id="FormId" name="editForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" #editForm="ngForm">


<tr class="patient" *ngFor="let paciente of pacientes ;trackBy: trackId">
```

here is the test, the new element is inserted in the end so it's index is length-1, you can check that it's value is equal to your input value

```
it('should submit the form and save data', async(() => {
   let formElement: DebugElement;
   formElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#FormId'));
   formElement .triggerEventHandler('ngSubmit', null);
   expect(component.save).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // check that save is called on sybmit
   const tableLength = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.patient')).length;
   expect(tableLength ).toBe(1) // check that the element is added and length pass from 0 to 1
   expect(fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.patient'))[tableLength-1].nativeElement.value).toEqual(component.paciente.nombre)

  }))
```

Comment: I gotta edit my question, beacuse actually I have tested that save function is called, and I have tested already that save function really saves a new patient. The thing I want is to test if this patient appears in table, or maybe test the search button that searched for a patient in the table would be more appropriate.

Comment: yes you can check that by checking the length of your table tr, if the length pass from 0 to 1 that means 100% that there is a new tr added

Comment: But if I add anew one again it should pass from 1 to 2 right_

Comment: no, the length have to be equal to 0 on init, or you can initialize your patients list, the test will be always executed on the same init state

Comment: Ok but you here do not tests that teh table will be updated with teh data that you entered!!!

Comment: check my answer, you can check the value of the last element (length-1) and compare it to your input value of component property

Comment: have a look at this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467891/navigation-testing-in-angular