# Navigation testing in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to test this routerLink in angular.

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary float-right jh-create-entity create-paciente" [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: { popup: ['paciente-new'] } }]">
```

And my route.ts is this

```html
export const pacientePopupRoute: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'paciente-new',
        component: PacientePopupComponent,
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_DOCTOR', 'ROLE_USER'],
            pageTitle: 'oncosupApp.paciente.home.title'
        },
        canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService],
        outlet: 'popup'
    },
```

To test that this button really gets me to that component is it enough to test that the contain of the innerHTML of this button is equal to the paciente-new? Or I should enter more in the router.ts??

Comment: @Fateh Mohamed have  a look

Comment: Have you take a look at [Testing-Routing component](https://angular.io/guide/testing#routing-component)?